# Can I use WooCommerce in a headless CMS setup?

Tags: theme-development, headless

I don't have a question about coding in WordPress, but I was just wondering if I have a headless CMS setup, can I still have ecommerce functionality with WooCommerce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  WooCommerce has endpoints and you can access them with the standard WordPress REST API.

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/<id>
```

Did a little search and found that they have documentation available here: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/